# how do i handle the delete button without rendering the child component

Tags: reactjs

How do I handle the delete button without rendering the child component, the delete button must appear inside the card whether rendered by the parent or child component.
Is there another way to pass props to a child component without rendering the child itself?
Thanks in advance...

```
const cardone = <CardOne />;
class LoginForm extends Component {
 state = {
   card1: cardone,
 };

 handleDelete = () => {
   if (this.state.card1 !== <CardOne />) return this.setState({ card1: "" });
   else return this.state.card1;
   console.log("yeaah");
 };

 render() {
   return (
     <div className="site-card-wrapper">
       <Row gutter={18} style={{ marginTop: 250 }}>
         <Col
           span={7}
           style={{
             marginLeft: 80,
             marginRight: 15,
           }}
         >
           <CardOne onDelete={this.handleDelete} />;{this.state.card1}
         </Col>
         <Col span={7} style={{ marginRight: 15 }}>
           {this.state.card1}
         </Col>
         <Col span={7}>
           <Card id="003" bordered={false}>
             <h1 style={{ marginLeft: 140 }}>Item 3</h1>
             Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
             industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
             ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of
             type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
             survived not only five centuries
             <Button type="primary" style={{ marginTop: 20 }} block danger>
               Delete
             </Button>
           </Card>
         </Col>
       </Row>
     </div>
   );
 }
}
```

here is the Card component (antd Card)

```
  
  state = { delete: this.props.onDelete };

 
    
 
  render() {
    return (
      <Card bordered={false}>
        <h1 style={{ marginLeft: 140 }}>Item 1</h1>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
        industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
        since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
        scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five
        centuries
        <Button
          onClick={this.state.delete}
          type="primary"
          style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
          block
          danger
        >
          Delete
        </Button>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

export default CardOne;
```

Comment: Sorry your question is unclear. When you click on the delete button, the card should delete isn't it? If it delete, then it will not be rendered.

Comment: yah the card should delete, and to delete you have to update the state so my question is how can the card component access the state of the loginForm without being rendered by the logInForm

Comment: added answer to show how you can render a child component conditionally base on state.

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally render a component by checking the state. In this example, you can set card1 to null, and only render the component if it's not null.

This is just an example, you need to adjust the codes to your own usage.

```
class LoginForm extends Component {
 state = {
   card1: cardone,
 };

 handleDelete = () => {
   this.setState({ card1: null }) //set card1 to null so it will not be rendered
 };

 render() {
   return (
     <div className="site-card-wrapper">
       <Row gutter={18} style={{ marginTop: 250 }}>
         <Col
           span={7}
           style={{
             marginLeft: 80,
             marginRight: 15,
           }}
         >
           { card1 && <CardOne onDelete={this.handleDelete} /> } //Add this line to conditionally show CardOne component
           {this.state.card1}
         </Col>
         <Col span={7} style={{ marginRight: 15 }}>
           {this.state.card1}
         </Col>
         <Col span={7}>
           <Card id="003" bordered={false}>
             <h1 style={{ marginLeft: 140 }}>Item 3</h1>
             Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
             industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
             ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of
             type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
             survived not only five centuries
             <Button type="primary" style={{ marginTop: 20 }} block danger>
               Delete
             </Button>
           </Card>
         </Col>
       </Row>
     </div>
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot man thats what i wanted to do but didn't know how.